# Using Restlet in a web application

Tags: web-applications, restlet

Can I use restlet framework even if I am not implementing web services in a java web application.
I am developing a web application which would have a web service and also some services which can be implemented in a servlet. I am going to use Restlet framework for the web services, but can I use the same technology for a service which is not a web service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can use a templating language like freemarker to produce html output, You can use familiar restlet methods to extract query params and form post data.